# Possible to reuse a group of class aliases (use as) in multiple files?

Tags: php, oop

I have a bunch of classes in separate files that all need the same USE AS statements. For example:

```
use \Blueprint as bp;
use \Blueprint\Acf as acf;
use \Blueprint\Acf\Field as field;
```

Is there any way to reuse these, so I don't have to type them out at the top of every single file?

Comment: The short answer is: **No**. The scope of `use` aliases is the file where they are defined.

Comment: Just get a IDE that auto adds the `use` once you use it somewhere in the current file. PHPStorm is one of them. Start typing the class, let it autocomplete, press enter, it gets added as a `use` statement. Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **No**.

The documentation page ["Using namespaces: Aliases/Importing"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) explains in the ["Scoping rules for importing"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope) section:

> The `use` keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.
>
> **Note:**
>
> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will *NOT* inherit the parent file's importing rules.

As the quoted documentation explains above, the aliases are used on the compile time, they don't exist in the generated code. The inclusion of other files, on the other hand, happens during the runtime. The aliases defined in a file and the content of the files it includes never meet.

Answer (score 0):

No.

And, if your code needs so many namespace/classname imports in each file, then you have a considerable issue with [tight coupling](http://wiki.c2.com/?CouplingAndCohesion) in your codebase. It might indicate a more serious problem at the architectural level.

P.S.: you should import only the namespaces/classnames, that you actually need in that particular file.

Comment: They really just need the same three namespaces... so I wouldn't say that's a lot. And they all use those namespaces. Just trying to cut down on redundant code I have to write every time I add a class.

Comment: In such cases, I tend to import a namespace (or even parent namespace) and not a specific class.